# AWS AppSync Subscription Not Trigger During Network Status Change

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, subscription, react-apollo

Rather than providing too much details, I'd just like to ask if anyone has run into this issue.

I am using react-apollo. (React Native) Generally, it works well. I was able to subscribe to mutations and let my code trigger.

However, in the scenario like this, it seems not working or at least I feel it's inconsistent.

1. Leave your mobile application running in the foreground.
2. Go offline using the airplane mode.
3. Do some mutations on the server / other devices.
4. Turn on the network.
   *During the whole process, I'd left my app in the foreground.

Subscription event doesn't trigger. What I had been expecting was that it should receive all the pending publications since then, without any user interactions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same issue here. Even not working when I switch between Wifi and 4G network.

Comment: @user7532779 It looks like AppSync is still at an early stage to be considered as a solution. I'll stay on Google Firebase.

Comment: Hi, Have you found any solution for the same

Comment: nope. I won't spend any more time on AppSync